# Automated monitoring of a remote system that sends email alerts

Tags: monitoring, automation

I need to monitor a remote system where the only access I have is that I can subscribe to email alerts of completed/failed jobs. I would like a system that can monitor these emails and provide an SMS or other alert when:

- An email indicates failure.
- A process that was expected to complete by a
  given time has not.
- A process that was expected to complete N minutes
  after completion of another process
  has not completed.

Are there any existing tools that allow this? I'd consider any option - SaaS, open-source, COTS, as long as I don't have to write it myself!

Cheers,

Blake

Comment: So... you want an alert when you recieve an alert?

Answer (score 1):

Have your mail program forward messages to your phone's email address. Most email programs allow you to make rules where you forward based on subject line or body.

Answer (score 1):

> I would like a system that can monitor these emails and provide an SMS or other alert when...

That sounds like something a few pwerful Gmail *Filter* can do!

If you need Email to SMS support, there are many providers for that. Just google "Email SMS Gateway". Your mobile phone provider might offer that for free (mine does).